# Ant replaceregexp to match across more than one line

Tags: regex, ant

To match and replace any instances of this:

```
     </topichead>
<topicref
```

Using replaceregexp in ant, why isn't this working?

```
   <replaceregexp byline="false" flags="gis">
     <regexp pattern="&lt;/topichead&gt;\n&lt;topicref"/>
     <substitution expression="&lt;topicref"/>
     <fileset dir=".">
     <include name="*.txt"/>
     </fileset>
   </replaceregexp>
```

The task works if I just match and replace `&lt;/topichead&gt;` on a single line as a test.

My `\n` clearly isn't working to match the new line mark. I've tried `\r\n` there, I've tried ${line.separator} as well, but the result of the task is no change.

If I put the regular expression in `regex101.com` like this:

```
</topichead>\n<topicref
```

It tells me that it matches this content:

```
     </topichead>
<topicref
```

If I do it in `regex101.com` this way:

```
(</topichead>)(\n)(<topicref)
```

Then it matches the content as three capture groups. So clearly it's working there, why not in the Ant build?

Comment: Your example input has `topichead` followed by `topichead`. However, the Ant regular expression has `topichead` followed by `topicref`

Comment: Chad: Thx, fixed the typo. It should be like the regular expression and also like all the examples at the bottom.

Comment: No undesirable spaces before `<topicref` ?

Comment: zessx: Not that I see. If I put my cursor right after `</topichead>` and press right-arrow, I'm right at the start of `<topicref` on the next line.

Comment: Replacing `\n` with `\r\n` in the regular expression works for me.

Comment: Ok now that worked for me also. Not in the large file but I put a few lines in a new test file and changing to \r\n is working. Must be something about the original file, I'll take a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: maybe try `\r?\n` instead of `\r\n`